# Vibration/sound feedback on longClick

Tags: android

When the user clicks on a button (assuming the device is not in silent/vibration mode) a confirmation sound is played, along with vibration.

From what I can tell we can have this happen on a custom View by setting the `onClickListener` and invoking `performClick()`; I have noticed that no feedback is given if the listener is not set.

> Is there a way to just get the audio/vibration feedback without invoking the `onClick()` method?

I will need to implement `onClick()` for other reasons, so leaving the body empty does not work for me. Notice that the contrary is possible: with `callOnClick()` we can invoke the method *without* getting the feedback.

> In addition, long clicks have no default feedback (at least on my devices). Any way to add it, again without resorting to `performClick()`?

EDIT:

A workaround could be using a dummy View to perform an empty click on. But I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution without this overhead.

Comment: And You need make phone vibration and make a sound when click on a button?

Comment: Well, I need the feedback when long clicking (which Android does not do by default)

Comment: DIY - Try this code

Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) ;
Then in the OnLongClickListener of your button:

vibe.vibrate(50); // 50 is time in ms
And dont forget you need to add the permission to the manifest (after the </application> tag):

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

Comment: @ThanhLe thanks for you input. I was aware of your proposed solution, which does indeed work, but I would like a more elegant solution (which should not require any permission, since the app is allowed to give feedback by default when normal clicking)

Comment: @Angelo Rendina vibrate is a "normal" level permission meaning it needs to be in the manifest but it is accepted by default. You don't need to ask the user for permission.